# iOS show webview offline with images

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to download a webpage (html) then display the local html that has been downloaded in a UIWebView. It is working, but the offline UIWebView doesn‘t show me the images.
This is my code:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"index.html"];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.mypage.com"];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];



[Website loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];




}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

Can anyone share some sample code to add the website content (the images)?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the HTML references images that you aren't also downloading. The first step would be to parse the HTML and download the images too. Then you may need to fix the local copy of HTML if the image references aren't relative to the base document. For example, if they refer to images on a different server, you'll have to fix those links internally. And if the original document uses Javascript to load images dynamically, it may never work the way you want.